# How to test useEffect with Auth api and state inside

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

```
useEffect(()=>{
  Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then((user) => {
    setUser(user)
    setIsLoading(false)
    if (user.challengeName === 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED') {
      navigate('/ForceChangePassword')
    }
    else{
      navigate('/App')
    }
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('isCurrentAuthenticatedUser- ',error)
      setUser(null)
       setIsLoading(false)
    })
  });
```

Comment: can you specify the question a little bit more?

Comment: @Manik Kumar do you want to test the user state?

Comment: @Jithin actually my point is I am not able to cover the Auth part can you please let me know how can I do that?

Comment: @Gregfan so how can I cover that Auth part and after the state part which are setUser and setIsLoading although I am able to cover its catch block

Comment: What do you want to cover in the auth part?

Comment: @Jithin I think you are not able to understand the question, my point is I want to cover the statement starting from Auth and the else part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can simply mock the Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() part.
For example:-

```
        Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser = jest.fn().mockImplementation(()=>Promise.resolve({challengeName: 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED'}))
```

If someone wants to cover the catch block then:-

```
 Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser = jest.fn().mockImplementation(()=>Promise.reject())
```